# Erro de stack overflow ao validar DateTime no setter

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Tenho uma classe chamada `Appointment` com um atributo string (que quero, em outra etapa do projeto, transformá-lo em `DateTime`) cujo setter usa o método `DateTime.TryParse()` para verificar se a String pode ser convertida para `DateTime`, da seguinte forma:

```
class Appointment
{
    DateTime dateValue; //Used for validation with DateTime.TryParse()
    public string Content { get; set; }
    private bool ValidDate;
    public string Date
    {
        get { return Date; }
        set
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateValue))
            {
                this.Date = value;
                ValidDate = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Já em outra classe, tenho um `List` que armazena abjetos da classe citada acima. Nela tenho um método chamado `Insert_appoint()` para instanciar e inserir um objeto do tipo `Appointment` dentro do `List`:

```
    private List<Appointment> Appointments = new List<Appointment>();
    public void Insert_Appoint(string element, string date)
    {
        Appointment Appoint = new(element, date);
        Appointments.Add(Appoint);
    }
```

Quando tento fazer fazer a operação na classe `Main`, mesmo usando como parâmetro uma String compatível com `DateTime`:

```
Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
schedule.Insert_Appoint("Do something", "15, 5, 2020");
```

ocorre um erro de [Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BZaz.png)

O que pode estar ocorrendo? Há alguma outra maneira de fazer essa validação? Ou então se eu estou usando a função `DateTime.TryParse()` de forma errada.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Este é o problema:

```
this.Date
```

Dentro do método que *seta* o `Date` o código está *setando* o `Date`, então ele cria uma execução recursiva sem fim, conforme mostra a imagem. Provavelmente quer algo assim:

```
using System;

public class Appointment {
    public string Content { get; set; }
    private bool validDate = false;
    private DateTime date;
    public string Date {
        get { return Date.ToString(); }
        set {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out var dateValue)) {
                date = dateValue;
                validDate = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Property.cs).

Eu inclusive dei uma melhorada no código, mas ele ainda parece errado, não posso afirmar qual é o certo sem saber o objetivo, mas nem parece que a propriedade desta forma deveria existir, algo assim parece fazer mais sentido:

```
using System;

public class Appointment {
    public string Content { get; set; }
    private bool validDate = false;
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public void SetDate(string date) {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out var dateValue)) {
            Date = dateValue;
            validDate = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/SetDate.cs).

Talvez possa deixar mudar a data de forma direta quando já tiver uma data, mas novamente, depende do objetivo.

Isso sequer é uma validação de fato. É só uma forma de ter um agendamento inicial sem uma data qualquer, o que costuma ser conceitualmente errado, mas não vou tentar resolver dos problemas da aplicação sem a conhecer detalhadamente.

A classe não está completa.

Comment: A aplicação é uma agenda. A ideia seria que o usuário entraria com uma string de data no set em que deve ser verificado se essa entrada pode ser convertida para DateTime. E posteriormente eu teria uma função para mostrar a data usando o DateTime.Parse().

Comment: Isso não quer dizer nada.